# Monkey Talk ide (v1.0.30) there is no record button (Using fire fox)

Tags: firefox, monkeytalk

I am a beginner in Monkey Talk. Kindly help me to start with it
I'm trying to use Monkey Talk for automation test. I installed it successfully. I connected it successfully with fire fox option.I am using fire fox v12.0 and windows xp with 2gb ram. In this ide there is no record button for recording user actions in fire fox. Can you please guide me. Thanks in advance.

I searched in gorrilla logic site but I din't get correct information...

Comment: Kindly tell us what you have tried and searched for online.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you had a look at the monkeytalk user guide. it says firefox only in beta5 is that the version you are using

Can I test HTML5 web apps?

Yes, as of MonkeyTalk Beta5 we now support agents for iOS, Android, Flex, desktop web browsers (Firefox only in Beta5), and mobile web. So you can test HTML5 apps in both a desktop web browser and our bundled MTBrowser application.